# How to delete pointer which has not been assigned to an object

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, game-engine

I'm new to C++ and I am currently working on a game. In the game, I'll have random enemy generation over time and I'm using a std::vector to do this. I thought I could use something like

```
enemies.push_back(new Enemy(random_x, randomY));
```

within a loop, but now it seems to me that this could lead to a memory leak since I'm not deleting the pointers. So I'd like to learn what should I do to prevent a memory leak; should I find a way to delete all the enemies I create or should I do something completely different?

Comment: Do it in a (iterator) loop over all elements in `enemies`.

Comment: What is the case for your enemies to die?

Do they die in a loop which checks for certain situations? Please share that code :)

Comment: What *are* you doing with those pointers? If they no longer have a lifetime they shouldn't be in your list. You may want to consider `std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Enemy> >` for the underlying type if you're concerned about such things (and frankly, even if you're not concerned).

Comment: I don't want to instantiate the enemies as soon as they are declared so that's why I'm using pointers. I guess I could use something like "delete enemies.at(i)" in a loop. Should this work?

Comment: Hmm, shared pointers seem to be what I'm looking for though, thanks.

Comment: Why the indirection? Is `Enemy` part of an inheritance hierarchy? How about `std::vector<Enemy> enemies;` and `enemies.push_back(Enemy(random_x, randomY));` (note the "missing" `new`)? Or even better, if your compiler supports C++11, `enemies.emplace_back(random_x, randomY);`

Comment: Wow I didn't know I could to that haha. Thanks a lot, that should help me a lot with current and future projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways to solve this.

You can use raw pointers, as in `std::vector<Enemy*>`, then you need to delete them as you remove them:

```
delete *pos; // pos is an iterator pointing to the element to be deleted
enemies.erase(pos);
```

However, this isn't the way to handle things in C++.

You can use `shared_ptr` if you want to pass the "enemies" around without having access to the list, as in `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Enemy>>`. Then you just need to erase, and the memory will be freed for you automatically, as soon as no `shared_ptr` which points to the enemy exists anymore.

```
enemies.erase(pos); // Nothing more needed, if someone still has a shared_ptr-copy 
                    // of the enemy it will stay in memory until that reference is gone
```

If you always access the enemy by using the list, you may even use a `std::unique_ptr`. But in this case it may be even better to just go with the simplest of all forms: `std::vector<Enemy>`. This way you don't ever have to call `new`. But this also keeps you from using polymorphism and the copies might be very expensive depending on your `Enemy`-class.

#### Why doesn't polymorphism work?

`std::vector<Enemy>` stores a complete `Enemy` in it's memory by copying it. If, for example, `Enemy` takes up 8 bytes in memory, and you have 5 enemies in the vector, it will in theory take up 40 bytes of memory (it may need more, but that is implementation specific)

```
| Idx0  | Idx1  | Idx2  | Idx3  | Idx4 |
[Enemy1][Enemy2][Enemy3][Enemy4][Enemy5]
   8b      8b      8b      8b      8b
```

If you try to store a derived `ExtraToughEnemy` object with added attributes at position 3 which needs let`s say 4 bytes extra, it won't work because each entry in the vector has to have the same size.

```
| Idx0  | Idx1  | Idx2  | Idx3  | Idx4 |
[Enemy1][Enemy2][ExtraToughEnemy3][Enemy4][Enemy5]
   8b      8b           12b          8b      8b
```

If you use pointers, you avoid this problem, since every pointer object has the same size, but can point to different derived objects.

```
|  Idx0  |  Idx1  |  Idx2  |  Idx3  |  Idx4 |
[Enemy1*][Enemy2*][Enemy3*][Enemy4*][Enemy5*]
   4b       4b       4b       4b       4b
```

A baseclass pointer can point to any baseclass or derived object. You will have to use a cast to access the extra attributes of `Enemy3*` though.

#### Note on shared pointers and unique pointers:

If you use them, you may consider (depending on your compiler), to even skip using `new` at all and use `std::make_shared` or `std::make_unique` to create the objects on the heap.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. But I don't get how can using `std::vector<Enemy>` can keep me from using polymorphism. Can you explain that?

Comment: @MertcanEkiz I have tried to give you an explaination, although it might not be the best one. There are many resources on the net covering this topic, just do a search for vectors and polymorphism and you will find enough info to make it more clear. If you don't plan on making any subclasses of `Enemy` it won't be of concern to you for now anyways.

Comment: That is a great explanation. You really made me understand a lot of things I couldn't understand before. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There's only a *memory leak* if you lose access to the object without first freeing up the backing store. This isn't the case here since you call find all those enemies just by walking through the `enemies` collection.

Presumably at some point you'll remove enemies from the list (when you kill them in the game, for example). At that point you should delete them and the memory will be reclaimed.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but deleting the elements of the list is the part that I don't understand completely I guess. For example if I had objects for all the enemies like `Enemy enemy1;` it would be simple to delete those, just call `delete enemy1`. But since that is incompatible with the dynamic list and big number of enemies I create, I was wondering if I could do something like `delete enemies.at(i)` in a loop when I'm done with them.

Comment: @MertcanEkiz, you can do that, sort of. The idea is to get the pointer _out_ of the vector, do what you have to do with it, then delete it.